# curses.addch returning error but not indicating why

Tags: python, curses

I'm writing a game in curses and for some reason I keep getting an error when trying to write to terminal. Previously I did not have a problem making the game boards in terminal. This issue started after I got the networking protocol written up. Here is my function:

```
def draw_player_board(stdscr, onion_address, max_y, max_x):
    try:
        # Fetch all players' data
        all_players_data = sorted(PLAYERS.values(), key=lambda x: x['player_id'] != onion_address)
        
        for player_data in all_players_data:
            cursor_positions = player_data["cursor_positions"]
            selected_color = player_data["selected_color"]
            grid = player_data["grid"]
            top_left_x = player_data["top_left_x"]
            top_left_y = player_data["top_left_y"]
            
            # Draw the grid border for the player's grid
            for i in range(GRID_ROWS + 2):
                if top_left_y + i < max_y:
                    if top_left_x - 1 >= 0:
                        logging.info(f"addch {top_left_y + i}, {top_left_x - 1} |")
                        ret = stdscr.addch(top_left_y + i, top_left_x - 1, '|')
                    if top_left_x + GRID_COLS < max_x:
                        logging.info(f"addch {top_left_y + i}, {top_left_x + GRID_COLS} |")
                        ret = stdscr.addch(top_left_y + i, top_left_x + GRID_COLS, '|')
            for i in range(GRID_COLS + 2):
                if top_left_y - 1 >= 0 and top_left_x + i < max_x:
                        logging.info(f"addch {top_left_y - 1}, {top_left_x + i}, _")
                        ret = stdscr.addch(top_left_y - 1, top_left_x + i, '_')
                if top_left_y + GRID_ROWS < max_y and top_left_x + i < max_x:
                        logging.info(f"addch {top_left_y + GRID_ROWS}, {top_left_x + i}, _")
                        ret = stdscr.addch(top_left_y + GRID_ROWS, top_left_x + i, '_')

            for col in range(GRID_ROWS):
                for row in range(GRID_COLS):
                    cell_x, cell_y = row + top_left_x, col + top_left_y
                    if (cell_x >= top_left_x and cell_x < top_left_x + GRID_COLS and
                        cell_y >= top_left_y and cell_y < top_left_y + GRID_ROWS):
                        if grid[col][row] != -1:
                            if cell_y < max_y and cell_x < max_x:
                                ret = stdscr.addch(cell_y, cell_x, "█", curses.color_pair(COLORS[grid[col][row]]))
                                logging.info(f"addch return value: {ret}")
                                player_data["top_left_x"] = cell_x
                                player_data["top_left_y"] = cell_y
                        else:
                            if cell_y < max_y and cell_x < max_x:
                                ret = stdscr.addch(cell_y, cell_x, " ")
                                logging.info(f"addch return value: {ret}")

            # Draw the player's cursor
            for cursor_position in cursor_positions:
                cursor_x, cursor_y = cursor_position
                if (cursor_x >= top_left_x and cursor_x < top_left_x + GRID_COLS and
                    cursor_y >= top_left_y and cursor_y < top_left_y + GRID_ROWS):
                    if cursor_y < max_y and cursor_x < max_x:
                        ret = stdscr.addch(cursor_y, cursor_x, "█", curses.color_pair(COLORS[selected_color]))
                        logging.info(f"addch return value: {ret}")
                else:
                    logging.info("Cursor outside of board bounds")
    except curses.error as curses_err:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        logging.info(f"Error in draw_player_board: {exc_type}, {fname}, {exc_tb.tb_lineno}, {curses_err}")
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        logging.info(f"Error in draw_player_board: {exc_type}, {fname}, {exc_tb.tb_lineno}, {e}")
```

and the error:

```
INFO:root:addch 74, 0, _
INFO:root:Error in draw_player_board: <class '_curses.error'>, 
Line 962, add_wch() returned ERR
```

Here is my updated code:

```
def draw_player_board(stdscr, onion_address, max_y, max_x, scroll_position):
    try:
        # Ensure scroll_position is initialized
        if scroll_position is None:
            scroll_position = 0

        # Fetch all players' data
        all_players_data = sorted(PLAYERS.values(), key=lambda x: x['player_id'] != onion_address)
        # Determine the start and stop indices for the visible area
        start_index = max(scroll_position, 0)
        stop_index = min(scroll_position + max_y - 2, len(PLAYERS) * (GRID_ROWS + 2))

        # Create the visible_area slice
        visible_area = slice(start_index, stop_index, 1)
        logging.info(f"visible_area: {visible_area}")

        # Determine the visible area based on the scroll position
        top_row = max(0, scroll_position)
        bottom_row = min(len(PLAYERS) * (GRID_ROWS + 2), max_y + scroll_position)
        
        for player_data in all_players_data:
            cursor_positions = player_data["cursor_positions"]
            selected_color = player_data["selected_color"]
            grid = player_data["grid"]
            top_left_x = player_data["top_left_x"]
            top_left_y = player_data["top_left_y"]
            # Calculate the indices of all border cells in a single line

            # Draw the grid content
            for col in range(visible_area.start, visible_area.stop, visible_area.step):
                for row in range(GRID_COLS):
                    cell_x, cell_y = row + top_left_x, col + top_left_y
                    if (cell_x >= top_left_x and cell_x < top_left_x + GRID_COLS and
                        cell_y >= top_row and cell_y < bottom_row):
                        if grid[col][row] > 0:
                            stdscr.addch(cell_y - scroll_position, cell_x, "█", curses.color_pair(COLORS[grid[col][row]]))
                        elif grid[col][row] == -1:
                            stdscr.addch(cell_y - scroll_position, cell_x, " ")

            # Draw the player's cursor
            for cursor_position in cursor_positions:
                cursor_x, cursor_y = cursor_position
                if (cursor_x >= top_left_x and cursor_x < top_left_x + GRID_COLS and
                    cursor_y >= top_row and cursor_y < bottom_row):
                    stdscr.addch(cursor_y - scroll_position, cursor_x, "█", curses.color_pair(COLORS[selected_color]))
                else:
                    logging.info("Cursor outside of board bounds")


    except curses.error as curses_err:
        logging.error(f"Error in draw_player_board: {curses_err}")
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        logging.info(f"Error in draw_player_board: {exc_type}, {fname}, {exc_tb.tb_lineno}, {e}")
```

Currently I'm trying to integrate the following solution but it's still erroring out. I have tried changing the size of the game board to be something smaller. But it doesn't seem to change the error:

```
            # Left border
            for left_index in [(i, top_left_x - 1) for i in range(top_row, bottom_row)]:
                stdscr.addch(left_index[0], left_index[1], "|")
            # Right border
            for right_index in [(i, top_left_x + GRID_COLS) for i in range(top_row, bottom_row)]:
                stdscr.addch(right_index[0], right_index[1], "|")
            # Top border
            for top_index in [(top_left_y - scroll_position, i) for i in range(top_left_x, top_left_x + GRID_COLS + 1)]:
                stdscr.addch(top_index[0], top_index[1], "-")
            # Bottom border
            for bottom_index in [(top_left_y + GRID_ROWS - scroll_position, i) for i in range(top_left_x, top_left_x + GRID_COLS + 1)]:
                stdscr.addch(bottom_index[0], bottom_index[1], "-")
```

Comment: Better add something like `traceback.print_exc()` to the except-blocks to print out the complete tracebacks (and then show them in the question).

Comment: "but not indicating why" -- that's because your `except` block prints **only** the final line of code that directly caused the error, deep inside the curses module, instead of the usual traceback showing the entire call chain.

Comment: @MichaelButscher is there a way to save this to a variable so I can commit it to a log? The terminal is refreshed so I cannot actually see it print the traceback.

Comment: `traceback.format_exception(e)` will return the exception message lines as text.

Comment: @JohnGordon

, ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "game.py", line 963, in draw_player_board\n    ret = stdscr.addch(top_left_y - 1, top_left_x + i, \'_\')\n          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n', '_curses.error: add_wch() returned ERR\n']

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409924/curses-error-addwstr-returned-err-on-changing-nlines-to-1-on-newwin-method) might be why it is crashing

Comment: Hmm. Didn't seem to change the results. Still getting the error

Comment: Your terminal has 75 (or more) lines?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Where do you see that? Are you implying that there are too many lines for the terminal? My solution that I was looking into last night was to enable some sort of scrolling with curses.

Ah I think I see now. You're talking about the indexing? Yes, the grids are gameboards. I was hoping to enable some sort of zooming for the game boards.

Comment: Your log says `addch 74, 0`, so `addch` is called with this value for the `y` parameter.

Comment: Yes, that's accurate. It is intending to do that. Are you implying that it's out of bounds of the size of the terminal?

Comment: He's _asking_ if it's out of bounds.  He _asked_ if your terminal has at least 75 lines. 
 He asked, and you did not answer.  It's quite frustrating to try and help people when they won't answer simple questions...

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe you could uninstall the attitude module. Reported.

Comment: This is probably the answer to your question: [curses fails when calling addch on the bottom right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387625/curses-fails-when-calling-addch-on-the-bottom-right-corner)